# How to generate function in runtime?

Tags: c++, macros, operating-system, c++14

I'm trying to write Interruption Service Routine in C++, here is some code snippet

```
void handlerProxy(int intrNo) {}

typedef void(*IntrHandler)();

IntrHandler IDT[256];
```

I want to initialize `IDT` in run-time or compile-time like this:

```
for (size_t i = 0; i < 256; ++i) {
    // It doesn't compile
    IDT[i] = std::bind(handlerProxy, i);
    // or
    IDT[i] = [i] () {handlerProxy(i);};
}
```

The problem is

- lambda function with capture can not be converted to function pointer
- My code will be compiled with `-fno-rtti`, so `std::function::target` is not available

Is there any possibility I can manage to do this?
I don't want to write `IDT[0]= ... IDT[1]=...` manually or use other program to generate it. Macro and inline asm is allowed. Type of `IDT` can be changed, however the element of `IDT` should be function address, which means something like `jmp IDT[0]` should be valid.

Comment: Would making the type of `IDT[]` a `sturct` with the function call operator overload (function object) be out of the question?

Comment: @Galik In that case `jmp IDT[0]` won't work. BIOS invokes those functions just by `push` registers and flags and  `jmp` to the address

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could make `intrNo` a template parameter like so:

```
template <int intrNo>
void handlerProxy() {}

typedef void(*IntrHandler)();
```

and initialize the array using a pack expansion:

```
template <typename IS>
struct helper;

template <size_t ... Is>
struct helper<std::index_sequence<Is...>> {
  static constexpr std::array<IntrHandler, sizeof...(Is)> make_handlers() {
    return {{ &handler_proxy<Is> ... }};
  }
};

constexpr std::array<IntrHandler, 256> IntrHandlers = helper<std::make_index_sequence<256>>::make_handlers();

IntrHandler * IDT = IntrHandlers.data();
```

(caveat emptor, code not tested)

Comment: It works, although `IntrHandlers.data()` can't be assigned to `IntrHandler *` directly -- just need a little modification.

Answer (score 1):

Chris's answer is more compact, However this can be done with tuple, define handlerProxy as a templated function object with a static member:

```
template <int i>
    struct handlerProxy{
    static int func(){return i * i;}
};
```

then function to create tuple of pointer to functions:

```
template <size_t... I>
decltype(auto) functions(std::index_sequence<I...>) {
         return return std::make_tuple(&handlerProxy<I>::func...);
}
template <size_t size>
decltype(auto) generate_functions() {                                                      
   using Indices = std::make_index_sequence<size>;
   return functions(Indices{});
}
```

use:

```
int main()
{
    //generate tuple of functions
    auto IDT = generate_functions<256>();
    //call 2th function
    std::cout << std::get<2>(IDT)();
}
```

note: -ftemplate-depth option in gcc should be set to relatively large  number ,50000, to compile

Comment: I don't think it can work. Notice in my question I need things like `jmp IDT[0]` to be valid. Every element in `IDT` must be an 32-bit address. Although `std::get<2>(IDT)()` works, but it's BIOS that will invoke those functions. BIOS doesn't know `operator ()`, BIOS only `jmp` to the address without passing any parameter.

Comment: Maybe I can use the address `&handlerProxy<0>::operator ()`, `&handlerProxy<1>::operator ()` ... to fill the `IDT` array, but I'm not sure whether simple `jmp` to this address in asm can always invoke the function correctly.

Comment: I mean member function always has a hidden parameter `this`, but BIOS won't pass this parameter so I'm not sure whether it will have some side effects.

Comment: @Slardar Zhang I edited the code. instead of operator() use a static member function